# Chromedriver is not found although it opens chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a site to extract some tags. I have downloaded `chromedriver` and moved it to the script folder.

When I run the below script, it opens chrome and navigates to the correct site. Although that is where it stops. I have tried numerous different variations of locations for the `chromedriver`

This is the script below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/jasonbeedle/Desktop/snaviescraper/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.canalplus.com/programme-tv/')

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Navigate to url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.canalplus/programme-tv")
driver.quit

results = driver.find_elements_by_class(
    'cardTitle')

print(results.text)
```

The error I get is: `chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH`

Comment: why are you calling webdriver.Chrome() so many times?  Only need to do it once.

Comment: Okay noted. I have changed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_class('cardTitle')
```

after you already closed the driver.

With that in mind, and by losing superfluous driver initializations, your script should look something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/jasonbeedle/Desktop/snaviescraper/chromedriver'

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

# Navigate to url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.canalplus/programme-tv")


results = driver.find_elements_by_class(
    'cardTitle')

print(results.text)

driver.quit
```